# Structuring reactive Query building in a Shiny app and exporting the results

Tags: r, shiny

I have a built a Shiny app which queries a local database and returns the results in table. There are two queries which can be ran, each of which is controlled by a separate action button.

The app works fine, but I ran into an issue when trying to make a data-download button. The problem is that I have made two separate reactive functions to get each query, and I can't work out how to make the results of both queries the same 'object' [pardon the terminology which is probably incorrect] so that the same data-download button will download the current data depending on which query was ran. An ugly fix for this is to just make two download buttons, but I'm sure there's an elegant solution.

Here is my code:

**global.R**:

```
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(igraph)

# Import parts list and materials list
setwd("REDACTED/Scripts/shiny/LegislationQuery/")
partList <- read.csv("partList.csv")
materialsList <- read.csv("materialsList.csv")

# Set up local.db
if(file.exists("local.db")) file.remove("local.db")
myDB<-dbConnect(SQLite(),"local.db")
dbWriteTable(myDB, "partList", partList, overwrite = TRUE)
dbWriteTable(myDB, "Materials", materialsList, overwrite = TRUE)
```

**server.R**:

```
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(igraph)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 sqlDown <- reactive ({paste("with recursive Parts(P,S, Level) as (select Part as P, SubPart as S, 0 from partList union select Parts.P, partList.SubPart as S, Parts.Level + 1 as Level from Parts, partList where Parts.S = partList.Part) select P as Part, S as SubPart,  Level from Parts where P = ","'", input$partForQuery, "'", sep = "")})
 sqlUp <- reactive ({paste("with Parts(subPart, part, level) as (select SubPart as subPart, Part as part, 0 as level from partList where subPart =", "'", input$partForQuery, "'", "union select partList.SubPart, partList.Part as part, Parts.level - 1 as level from Parts, partList where Parts.part = partList.SubPart) select subPart as SubPart, part as Part, level as Level from Parts", sep = "")})

  queryDownData  <- function() {dbGetQuery(myDB, sqlDown())}
  queryUpData  <- function() {dbGetQuery(myDB, sqlUp())}

  observeEvent(input$RunDownQuery, {
    output$table <- renderDataTable(data.table({
    data = queryDownData()}))
    })
  observeEvent(input$RunUpQuery, {
    output$table <- renderDataTable(data.table({
    data = queryUpData()}))
    })  

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$partForQuery, '.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(queryDownData(), file)
    }
  )
})
```

**ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Part Query"),

  sidebarPanel(
  textInput("partForQuery", "Part Number:"),

    fluidRow(
    actionButton("RunDownQuery", label = "Run Query (Down)"),
    actionButton("RunUpQuery", label = "Run Query (Up)")
    ),
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
  ),

  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(igraph)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  whichQuery <- c()

  sqlDown <- reactive ({paste("with recursive Parts(P,S, Level) as (select Part as P, SubPart as S, 0 from partList union select Parts.P, partList.SubPart as S, Parts.Level + 1 as Level from Parts, partList where Parts.S = partList.Part) select P as Part, S as SubPart,  Level from Parts where P = ","'", input$partForQuery, "'", sep = "")})
  sqlUp <- reactive ({paste("with Parts(subPart, part, level) as (select SubPart as subPart, Part as part, 0 as level from partList where subPart =", "'", input$partForQuery, "'", "union select partList.SubPart, partList.Part as part, Parts.level - 1 as level from Parts, partList where Parts.part = partList.SubPart) select subPart as SubPart, part as Part, level as Level from Parts", sep = "")})

  queryDownData  <- function() {dbGetQuery(myDB, sqlDown())}
  queryUpData  <- function() {dbGetQuery(myDB, sqlUp())}

  observeEvent(input$RunDownQuery, {
    whichQuery <<- "Down"
    output$table <- renderDataTable(data.table({
      data = queryDownData()}))
  })
  observeEvent(input$RunUpQuery, {
    whichQuery <<- "Up"
    output$table <- renderDataTable(data.table({
      data = queryUpData()}))
  })  

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$partForQuery, '.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(ifelse(whichQuery=="Down",queryDownData(),queryUpData()), file)
    }
  )
})
```

`whichQuery` holds which button was pressed last, and then uses that value when determining which file to download.

Comment: Had to make a small edit, because for some reason having the ifelse inside the write.csv call made the output incorrect (some type handling issue I suspect). So I made a holder object, and did the ifelse outside of the write.csv call and it works great! Thanks for the help.